# Adding a popup to Azure AD B2C sign-up page

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, aad-b2c

I'm trying to add a password complexity pop-up whenever the new password field on the sign-up page is focused but it doesn't seem like Azure AD B2C has a custom policy element for that.

A suggestion of the best approach to achieve the above would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

[example of the desired new password field from Facebook sign-up page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziUzi.png)

Comment: you could add custom javascript / css to handle that i would think: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-and-page-layout?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

Comment: Thanks, Thomas! Yeah, I think I will have to go with this approach.